# How to move 2 edges in different ways (symmetry)? Blender 2.79

Tags: modeling

How to move 2 edges to different ways (with symmetry)? I tried to use the scale tool, but it works only in Y-axis, not X-axis, what I need.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

1. Reset Mesh Scale, Rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  in object mode)
2. Select Edges in *Edit Mode*, press on keyboard <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>  .
3. Scale edges by X-Axis.